# SQL query for distinct records

Tags: mysql

here is my query

```
select  
    po.product_option_id,  
    po.product_id,  
    24 as option_id,  
    283 as option_value_id,  
    1 as quantity,  
    0 as subtract,  
    2.0000 as price,  
    '+' as price_prefix,  
    0 as points,  
    '+' as points_prefix,  
    0.00000000 as weight,  
    '+' as weight_prefix  
from oc_product_option po  
inner join oc_product_option_value pov  
on po.product_option_id = pov.product_option_id  
where po.option_id = 24
```

i need distinct records against po.product_id, now its return multiple records against same product_id

any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use mysql group by

```
group by po.product_id
```

that will give you **distinct** records **against product_id**

```
select  
    po.product_option_id,  
    po.product_id,  
    24 as option_id,  
    283 as option_value_id,  
    1 as quantity,  
    0 as subtract,  
    2.0000 as price,  
    '+' as price_prefix,  
    0 as points,  
    '+' as points_prefix,  
    0.00000000 as weight,  
    '+' as weight_prefix  
from oc_product_option po  
inner join oc_product_option_value pov  
on po.product_option_id = pov.product_option_id  
where po.option_id = 24 group by po.product_id
```

Comment: This is mysql problem. Actually, in other rdbms you can't use *group by* without aggregate function.